# How to loop a sound

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code to play a sound and open a userform when a command button is pressed in excel.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Call PlayIt
    RequestAssistanceUserForm.Show
End Sub

Sub PlayTheSound(ByVal WhatSound As String)
    If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = "" Then
        ' WhatSound is not a file. Get the file named by
        ' WhatSound from the Windows\Media directory.
        WhatSound = Environ("SystemRoot") & "\Media\" & WhatSound
        If InStr(1, WhatSound, ".") = 0 Then
            ' if WhatSound does not have a .wav extension,
            ' add one.
            WhatSound = WhatSound & ".wav"
        End If
        If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
            Beep            ' Can't find the file. Do a simple Beep.
            Exit Sub

        End If
    Else
        ' WhatSound is a file. Use it.
    End If
    sndPlaySound32 WhatSound, 0&    ' Finally, play the sound.
End Sub

Sub PlayIt()
    PlayTheSound "tada.wav"
End Sub
```

I would like the sound to loop until a button on the userform is pressed to stop it, but I'm not sure how to achieve this. If you are able to point me in the right direction (in terms of how to code this) it would be very much appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the sound should be played in loop and still other activities can happen in parallel?

Comment: @PankajJaju I don't need any other events to happen while the userform is activated, everything can be paused while the sound is looping, then when the button is pressed it all goes back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the const `Const SND_LOOP = &H8` which will continue playing sound in a loop until the next call to `PlaySound` is made.

I believe the API that you are using is

```
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 _
Lib "winmm.dll"  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, _
ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
```

Use the one which i have used below.

Try this

```
Declare Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "PlaySoundA" _
(ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Const SND_LOOP = &H8
Const SND_ASYNC = &H1

Sub StartSound()
    PlaySound "C:\Windows\Media\Chimes.wav", ByVal 0&, SND_ASYNC + SND_LOOP
End Sub

Sub StopSound()
    PlaySound vbNullString, ByVal 0&, SND_ASYNC
End Sub
```

More about the API [HERE- My Fav stop for API's](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/PlaySound.shtml)

Comment: That's correct, yes I was using that API. I've now switched over to your code and it's working great - thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Helped me too!

Answer (score 0):

You can simple loop the `PlayTheSound` call, and also call `DoEvents` to allow Excel to process the stop button click

```
' At Module scope
Private StopSound As Boolean

Sub PlayIt()
    Do
        PlayTheSound "tada.wav"
        DoEvents
    Loop Until StopSound
    StopSound = False
End Sub

Private Sub StopCommandButton_Click()
    StopSound = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This will play the sound as fast as the loop runs, try it out and see what happens...

Comment: I've tried that and it's not working. It's giving me a variable not defined error on the `StopSound` on the `Loop Until StopSound` line.